# MapReduce: executing WordCount v1.0

Tags: java, apache, hadoop, mapreduce

I am trying to learn MapReduce from the official [documentation](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.2.1/mapred_tutorial.html). To make a jar file for WordCount class, the documentation says to run the following command:

```
javac -classpath ${HADOOP_HOME}/hadoop-${HADOOP_VERSION}-core.jar -d wordcount_classes WordCount.java
```

But, I found that my Hadoop directory has no `core.jar` present. I suppose my Hadoop installation is alright as I can execute the *Hadoop* shell script from the *Bin* folder.

Comment: I suggest that you at least describe your hadoop configurations setup. Like what version of Hadoop you are using per example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you trying with that:

```
javac -classpath `hadoop classpath` -d wordcount_classes WordCount.java
```

Isn't the best practice, I think, but work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Check in your hadoop-1.2.1 folder (*as in my case*), which you unzipped in "**Prepare to Start Cluster**" of [single node setup](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.2.1/single_node_setup.html). There you would find **hadoop-1.2.1-core.jar**

That is the file being used to compile here.